# Find a variable with concatenation

Tags: vb.net, variables, concatenation

I would like to find a variable with concatenation.

Exemple :

```
Dim oExcelRangeArray1(0, 0) As Object
Dim oExcelRangeArray2(0, 0) As Object
Dim oExcelRangeArray3(0, 0) As Object

For i As Integer = 1 To 3
    oExcelRangeArray & i = xl.Range("A1:Z400").Value
Next
```

but `oExcelRangeArray & i` doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: why you need a two diamentional array to store a single value  like `xl.Range("A1:Z400").Value`

Comment: For the lines and columns of my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the extent of my knowledge, there is no way to achieve what you are trying to do directly, because `oExcelRangeArray & i` will not be evaluated as a separate step before the variable assignment happens.

In my mind you have two choices:

1. Assign each variable individually,

   ```
   oExcelRangeArray1 = x1.Range("A1:Z400").Value
   oExcelRangeArray2 = x1.Range("A1:Z400").Value
   oExcelRangeArray3 = x1.Range("A1:Z400").Value
   oExcelRangeArray4 = x1.Range("A1:Z400").Value
   ```
2. Or, add each array to a list, and iterate through it,

   ```
   Dim oExcelRangeArrayList As New List(Of Object)
   oExcelRangeArrayList.Add(oExcelRangeArray1)
   oExcelRangeArrayList.Add(oExcelRangeArray2)
   oExcelRangeArrayList.Add(oExcelRangeArray3)
   oExcelRangeArrayList.Add(oExcelRangeArray4)

   For i As Integer = 0 To 3
       oExcelRangeArrayList(i) = x1.Range("A1:Z400").Value
   Next
   ```

[Note: Writing this freehand without checking it, code may not be verbatim; hopefully you get the concept. Corrections welcome.]

Comment: I just edited your message, missed the "New", its `New List (Of Object)`